# When will NG-Zorro supports Resizable column

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

We develop the webpage using antd-nozzo with Angular,but find not supporting resizable columns.

I found Antd Design of react has supported it. so when will ng-zorro supports this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout with our recent experimental component Resizable.

https://ng.ant.design/experimental/resizable/en

Comment: tks for your reply. 
so when will it be available in product version?  and will it be conflict with virtual scrolling?

Comment: @WisonHe You can use it now. There may be breaking changes of these experimental components occasionally. But we will never remove them.